# jQuery Mobile checkbox refresh slow

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to refresh 500+ checkboxes with jQuery Mobile, on desktop performance is alright but on mobile its really slow.
Checkboxes are being generated dynamically through AJAX. If I don't refresh them performance is fine.

I am using

```
$(".selector").checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Any idea how to optimize it so it runs faster?

Thanks.

Comment: are you appending them to the active page or different (hidden) page? if a different page, you dont need to call refresh method.

Comment: I am appending them to Slide Panel

Comment: Append them all without enhancement methods, once you finish, call `$('page_id').trigger('pagecreate');`. This will enhance them all at once.

Comment: First let me tell you this is a BIG mistake, jQuery Mobile is simply not built to handle large forms on mobile devices. Omar gave you an useful advice, use $('page_id').trigger('pagecreate'); It will use only one action to style everything where in your case every new checkbox will require separate styling procedure.

Comment: I am refreshing at the end of script (when all the checkboxes are generated). But its the requirement to show all of them.
I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: This will enhance them all at once. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/c2Ujn/